# ASP.NET 5 Upload file to API stream and pass to MongoDB GridFS

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, .net-5, gridfs, c#-9.0

I am trying to create an ASP.NET API endpoint that accepts a `multipart/form-data` POST request, processes it in a stream and have it asynchronously be uploaded to MongoDB using GridFS stream upload. Essentially, I do not want to buffer the whole file on the API server's disk and instead run it all through memory with as little handling as possible.

So far, I have been looking at various pieces of documentation (such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#file-upload)) trying to understand how it links together but I've been stuck on things like outdated libraries and missing explanations for some of the classes such as the MultipartReader which I don't really understand.

My code currently has a service class to handle the upload to MongoDB which has a method like this:

```
public async Task<string> UploadFromStreamAsync(Stream stream, string filename)
{
    var id = await _bucket.UploadFromStreamAsync(filename, stream);
    return id.ToString();
}
```

I also have the `UploadsController` class which extends ASP.NET's `ControllerBase` with a method for handling HTTP POST requests. How can I connect these two classes so that the controller picks up the upload parts and passes them on to the upload service in a stream so that the file can be uploaded to MongoDB at the same time it is uploaded to the API server?

I am using ASP.NET version 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, but I do not know how to verify if the no buffering requirement is being met. This implementation may have issues scaling with multiple simultaneous uploads, but I do not know for sure.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<FileUploadResponse>> FileUpload(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file.Length <= 0) return BadRequest();
            
    var fileId = await _fileUploadService
        .UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), file.FileName);
            
    return Ok();
}
```

The `FileUploadService` from the question remained unchanged.